# Mann-Whitney U-test in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm doing a Mann Whitney U test in R but it won't run the code:

```
downstream<-subset(mydata,Direction=="D")
Wilcox.test(Date, Species, data="downstream")
```

Species is categorical (`AS` and `BT`). and date as in Julian date (number of days from jan 1) the error code is:

Error in wilcox.test.formula(Julian.Date ~ Species, data = downstream) : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

I have seen this done with this code but when just copy the code I get the error above.

So if anyone knows how I can run a Mann-Whitney U-test on this I would be most grateful.

Comment: How is it that your response variable is a Julian date? What does that mean? Can you say more about your situation, your data & your goals?

Comment: I'm also confused about how the date is the response, but I think you're using the package wrong. First, with the way you're using it, date is the **x** variable. See the documentation https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html. Second, you should have have a separate argument for each category. It shouldn't all be jumbled up in one variable.

Comment: Please clarify more clearly what your variables are and what you're trying to achieve before discussing how to do it in R.

Comment: I want to see the relationship for date and the appearance of two species of fish. I partially know my results and that BT will appear later than AS.